# What kind of components are these (2)?

Tags: capacitor, identification, ceramic

What kind of components are these?

[image]

[image]

It shows:

GA
62A
And a symbol

Does anybody know what specs these can have?

(note: updated the question since they were not capacitors).

Comment: Silicon, metal, epoxy, and not a bit of ceramics in these, I bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the General Semiconductor logo.

I think they're vishay GF1A rectifier diodes they 62a is a date code for Feb 2006 and factory 'a'

Answer (score 2):

Those parts are very hard to see inside the tube. None the less I would suspect that these could also be SMT power diodes or TRANZORB type transient suppressors.

Comment: I tried to make a better picture but the focus is very hard.

Comment: You could take the part out of the tube before taking a picture of it.

Comment: Done (it's indeed much clearer now).